# What kind of value does android:valueTo represent

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation, android-xml

So I've been scouring the Android documentation trying to find out what kind of value `android:valueTo`, in , actually represents/takes, but with no luck. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#obj-animator-element) has the following to say:

```
android:valueTo:
   float, int, or color. Required. The value where the animated property ends. 
   Colors are represented as six digit hexadecimal numbers (for example
   , #333333).
```

Now that only tells me the value type (float, int, color), but not what it represents. For instance if I use the following code to animate the x coordinates of a view does the value in `android:valueTo` take on the format that the view's property accepts (if the property allows % or dp then you could use either here), does float always represent % and int always dp or even something else?

```
<objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:valueTo="-50"
        android:valueType="intType"/>
```

How ever using % or dp isn't allowed in the field, only using real numbers, so figuring this out by trial and error hasn't worked out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I've been able to gather from blog [posts](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) and [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UbJhmkeSig), it would seem that the values that objectAnimator properties can take vary between properties. For instance, scale represents percentage scaling, so value 2 represents 200%. And translationX uses dp, so 2 and 300 are both in dp.
Thus usage of %, %p or dp, as was possible in animation sets prior to Android 3.1, doesn't seem to be possible in the new framework.